# data-toggle="dropdown" colour upon click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to understand what exactly data-toggle="dropdown" does in my nav bar and it seems that the primary purpose is for touch screen surfaces, so that when the nav link is clicked, the menu stays open unlike a menu upon hover. (Please correct me if I'm wrong) to my rudimentary knowledge it changes the link to an active link??

So based on the code below when I click on the navbar link which is publications, it stays highlighted, how do I change the color of this highlight?

What line of CSS in bootstrap do I edit?

Thanks!

Update:

Using

.dropdown-toggle:focus {color:red;text-decoration: none;}

on its own doesn't work, I have to add '!important' to the line otherwise it doesn't take effect, maybe conflict with the bootstrap code?  Also, what I'm actually looking to do is not the text colour but the background colour. using background:color doesn't work at all for me.

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Publications</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="submissions.html">Submissions</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="coc.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Useful Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, if you are looking for color to stay till your `dropdown` is open, you should use pseudo `focus`

```
.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  color:red;  
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And if you are looking to change on `hover`, you can do it using the below code.

```
.dropdown-toggle:hover{
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can see in the below example.

On `hover` it's `green` and on `focus` it's `red`

---

```css
.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Publications</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="submissions.html">Submissions</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="coc.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Useful Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Great thanks! That's half the answer, unfortunately, I have to apply !important to get it to show, otherwise it doesn't seem to come into effect.  Also, it then causes strange things to happen, such as the original background will flash when i change the focus to another button. The original line in bootstrap.min.css doesn't have any formatting applied to this dropdown-toggle:focus. Which is very puzzling I need to apply !important to get it to override anything....

Comment: Please edit the question with specific problem you are having currently.